# Explanation of super(ClassName,self).__init__()

Tags: python, oop

I'm `C++` developer and i'm migrating to `python` , I prevent to :

```
def __init__(self): # definition of constructor
    super(ClassName,self).__init__()
```

But I don't know any idea on second line. Can you explain second line in `C++`?

Comment: Class that contains this method was inherited from a super class called `ClassName`. Therefore in this new class's constructor, the super class's `__init__` method is used. i.e. the constructor of it's parent class is used

Comment: Prevent mean i see in code lines...

Comment: @Oleksiy I'm sorry, but that is rather rude. OP's first language might not be Enligsh

Comment: for migration OOP is an essential.... Do you have any site for migration?

Comment: @Oleksiy Sure, incorrect English spelling is high-lighted, no matter the language of your OS... How did you manage then to spell "knownledge"? If you point your finger at others for their bad spelling, at least make sure your spelling is correct. Pathetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent to this c++ code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class parent {

protected:
    int n;
    char *b;
public:
    parent(int k): n(k), b(new char[k]) {
        cout << "From parent class\n";
    }
};

class child : public parent {

public:
    child(const int k) : parent(k){
        cout << "From child class\n";
        delete b;
    }
};


int main() {
    child init(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no precise equivalent in C++.  Please [read this](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for a good explanation :-)

In very simple (single inheritance) cases, the line you give simply calls the `__init__` method of `ClassName`s parent class.

Comment: Seems like the equivalent of `ClassName() : Base() {}`.